# how to execute task based on node role in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to execute receipe which validate chef environment and role:

**Recipe Example:**

```
if (node.chef_environment == "dev" && node.role?('api'))

    bash "Restarting service" do
      code <<-EOF
            #Codeblock
      EOF
    end
end

if (node.chef_environment == "dev" && node.role?('web'))

    bash "Restarting service" do
      code <<-EOF
            #Codeblock
      EOF
    end
end
```

But while executing my code block is not working.

I tried the condition "node["roles"].include?("api")" @coderanger but not working.
Here are the below debug logs:
2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] DEBUG: Loading cookbook service_file's resources from /etc/chef/chef-cache/cache/cookbooks/service_file/resources/default.rb
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /etc/chef/chef-cache/cache/cookbooks/service_file/resources/default.rb into resource service_file (Custom resource service_file from cookbook service_file)
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] DEBUG: Loading recipe service_file::service_restart via include_recipe
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] DEBUG: Found recipe service_restart_plugin in cookbook service_file
Converging 0 resources
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] DEBUG: Converging node ip-xx.xx.xx.xx
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.161187151 seconds
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] INFO: Skipping removal of unused files from the cache

Running handlers:
[2018-05-04T08:50:26+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
Running handlers complete

Comment: You should explain "is not working". Give more details, error message.

Comment: Try `node["roles"].include?("api")` instead.

Comment: @coderanger's advise worked for me.